Deriving Ray - Rounded Box intersection function based on a signed distance field
The signed distance $t$ of a query point $P$ to a rounded box at position $B_p$ with half dimensions $B_d$ and radius $B_r$ is defined as the following function, where $x$ and $y$ represent the vector components of $P$, $B_p$ and $B_d$:
$
P=P-B_p
$
$
t=\sqrt{max\left( P_x - B_{dx} , 0\right)^{2}+max\left( P_y - B_{dy}, 0 \right)^{2}}+min(maxcomp(P),0)-B_r
$
The function $max$ returns the component-wise maximum of its parameters, which means it is applied to each component of a vector separately if the other parameter is a scalar. The function $min$ does the same for the minimum. The function $maxcomp$ returns the maximum component of a given vector.
The square root section in this equation calculates the exterior distance of point $P$ to the unrounded box, the summand after that handles the interior distance in case $P$ is within the box and the subtraction of the radius $B_r$ in the end causes the box to have rounded edges. This algorithm is sourced from Inigo Quilez's website: https://iquilezles.org/articles/distfunctions/.
I want to transform this function in a way that, given a ray defined by an origin $R_o$ and a direction $R_d$, a distance $t$ is returned, which can be used to find the closest intersection point of the ray and the rounded box.
Any point on the ray $p$ has to satisfy the following equation, where $t$ is the distance along the ray to reach said point:
$
p=R_o+t*R_d
$
Further, any point $p$ on the surface of a signed distance field (SDF) as defined above has to satisfy the equation:
$
SDF(p)=0
$
My general thought here is:
Could I substitute the parameter $p$ in the SDF with it's defining formulation along a ray mentioned above and somehow create a function for gaining the distance $t$ to be travelled along the ray to reach an intersection point between the ray and the rounded box surface?
If not, why not?
An obvious hurdle are the $min$ and $max$ functions which don't have a mathematical equivalent as far as I know. How would you approach this task, if you consider it possible?
